# Validate the unescaped length of an element

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I've an XSD that defines a max length of 10 for an element. The string `"12345678'"` is invalid because it will be escaped to `"12345678&apos;"` and that is over 10 characters. I want `"12345678'"` to be valid as well but I've been unable to find a way on how to do this.

The XSD:

```
<xs:element name="ElementName">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:recordInfo notes="XXX" xmlns:b="XXX" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Element1">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo notes="XXX" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1" />
            <xs:maxLength value="10" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Element2">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:fieldInfo notes="XXX" xmlns:b="XXX" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1" />
            <xs:maxLength value="10" />
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 2):

From a data model perspective,  `&apos;` only counts as a single character and is the same as `'`. XML Schema is higher up in the levels of abstraction because it [consumes the XML infoset](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#xsover), where the entity reference is already resolved [as a character code](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#infoitem.character).

Some parsed entity references may [still appear in the XML infoset](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/#infoitem.rse), but this is only for external entities and non-validating processors (in the DTD validation sense) and as far as I know, XML Schema [does not explicitly reference them](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#infoset).

So I'm afraid that this is not possible in a straightforward way; but of course I would be happy to be proven wrong and learn something. Maybe using constraining facets with patterns and unions could work if one "explains" to XML Schema what characters are considered to be escaped, but it would probably need some effort, and this would still not distinguish between `'` and `&apos;` on the syntactic level.